# Syntax error: word unexpected on io redirection on file descriptor ≥10

Tags: shell, shell-script, io-redirection

I have the following shell script on debian 7:

```
#!/bin/sh


case "$IFACE" in
    lo)
        # The loopback interface does not count.
        # only run when some other interface comes up
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

(
flock -e 200

FLAGFILE=/var/run/cyvo-auto-started

if [ -e $FLAGFILE ]; then
    exit 0
else
    touch $FLAGFILE
fi

# Launch CyVo without the lock and as cyvo user
flock -u 200
sudo -u cyvo /usr/local/bin/cyvo-launch.sh

) 200>/var/lock/cyvo-autostart-lock # word unexpected here? (line 29)
```

The error it hives me is:

```
./cyvo: 29: ./cyvo: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

This is really confusing to me because it's the syntax suggested by the [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) command. It's to pass file descriptor 200 pointing to `/var/lock/cyvo-autostart-lock` to the subroutine in the `()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I wonder if /bin/sh can deal with file descriptors longer than 1 digit.

Comment: Add `set -x` on top of the script.

Comment: @val0x00ff What does that do?

Comment: @glennjackman Is it possible that there are any conflicting file descriptors if I only use one digit as file descriptor?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock `help set`  it shows how commands are executed etc. Try it and see it.

Comment: bash uses 0,1,2 (stdin, stdout, stderr). The rest are yours.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your question. Then others can benefit from your learning too

Comment: @glennjackman Why don't you answer the question? You came up with it so you should earn the reputation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only file descriptor numbers that you can portably use in a shell script are 0 through 9 (i.e. a single digit). Quoting [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

> Open files are represented by decimal numbers starting with zero. The largest possible value is implementation-defined; however, all implementations shall support at least 0 to 9, inclusive, for use by the application. These numbers are called "file descriptors". (…) The redirection operators can be preceded by one or more digits (with no intervening <blank> characters allowed) to designate the file descriptor number.

The [grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_01) is clear that there can be multiple digits before the redirection operator. Yet most shells only parse the number before the operator as a file descriptor if it consists of a single digit. For example, according to the POSIX specification, `echo 10>a` should either redirect file descriptor 10 to `a` and create an empty file, or error out because the shell doesn't support 10 as a file descriptor number. An error could also be due to the file descriptor number being over the process's limit for the number of open files.

But in practice most shells parse this as `echo 10 >a`, i.e. write `10` in `a`. Even ATT ksh93 and posh are non-compliant, as are dash, mksh and zsh:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo 10>a; wc -c a'
3 a
$ posh -c 'echo 10>a; wc -c a'
3 a
```

On Linux, I can only find bash, yash and BusyBox's ash that are POSIX-compliant on that point.

```
$ bash -c 'echo 10>a; wc -c a' 

0 a
```

Similarly, `(…) 200>somefile` should be parsed as a redirection, and may or may not work depending on whether the shell supports a file descriptor this high. But most shells instead report a syntax error, because they don't parse the `200` part as a file descriptor number but as an ordinary token.

On a related note, `echo 01>&1` should print an empty line, because `01` should be parsed as a file descriptor number, but again only bash and BusyBox ash get this right.

Thus, in practice, **you can only use single-digit file descriptors** in shell scripts. Descriptors 0, 1 and 2 have a standard meaning; descriptors 3–9 can be used freely. Shells won't use fd 3–9 for their internal purposes. No matter what file descriptor you choose, it's possible that the file descriptor is already open when the shell starts, but this shouldn't matter: any file descriptor reassignment in the script stays in the script and won't influence the script's parent process.

Answer (score 3):

On second thought, perhaps a more simple approach than my original answer (which I have reproduced below since that is what was originally accepted) is to change the file descriptor from `200` to something that is <9. For example, 5. So, change 
all three instances of `200` in your script to `5`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$IFACE" in
    lo)
        # The loopback interface does not count.
        # only run when some other interface comes up
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

(
flock -e 5

FLAGFILE=/var/run/cyvo-auto-started

if [ -e $FLAGFILE ]; then
    exit 0
else
    touch $FLAGFILE
fi

# Launch CyVo without the lock and as cyvo user
flock -u 5
sudo -u cyvo /usr/local/bin/cyvo-launch.sh

) 5>/var/lock/cyvo-autostart-lock
```

---

Original answer:

Either because `sh` can't deal with file descriptors >9 as @GlennJackman suggested or for some other peculiarity, your script doesn't work with `sh` (which is `dash` on Debian-based distributions). I tried with `bash` and it worked fine so just use `bash` instead. Change the first line from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The script should then work as expected.

Comment: @mikeserv yes indeed, that makes much more sense. Why not post an answer suggesting that so the OP can accept it instead?

Comment: @mikeserv fair enough, edited.