# Issue with redirecting output to double digit file descriptor

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

```
/tmp$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 13 2018, 12:45:42)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> f1 = open("/tmp/doo1","w")
>>> f2 = open("/tmp/doo2","w")
>>> f3 = open("/tmp/doo3","w")
>>> f4 = open("/tmp/doo4","w")
>>> f5 = open("/tmp/doo5","w")
>>> f6 = open("/tmp/doo6","w")
>>> f7 = open("/tmp/doo7","w")
>>> f8 = open("/tmp/doo8","w")
>>> f9 = open("/tmp/doo9","w")
>>> f5.fileno()
7
>>> os.system("cat /file_to_copy >&7")  # works fine
0
>>> f7.fileno()
9
>>> os.system("cat /file_to_copy >&9")  # works fine
0
>>> f8.fileno()
10
>>> os.system("cat /file_to_copy >&10")  # does not work
sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
512
>>> f9.fileno()
11
>>> os.system("cat /file_to_copy >&11")  # does not work
sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
512
```

Why only fd <= 9 is supported for I/O redirection? Did strace and could not figure out the issue. Even though I have pasted Python code, same issue is seen with C++ code since system invokes the shell.

My use case is to ssh into a remote machine and *cat* a remote file to local file. The local file was created earlier and immediately unlinked so that other user/process cannot see it. So redirecting cat output to local file fd instead of local filepath.

```
fd = open("/tmp/doo",O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
unlink("/tmp/doo");
...
...
system will run this - "ssh -n user@remotehost -- cat /remote_file >&fd"
```

edit - Looks like fd 10 and upwards are reserved.
From: https://github.com/MirBSD/mksh/blob/master/sh.h

```
/* first fd number usable by the shell for its own purposes */
#define FDBASE      10
/* … and last one */
#define FDMAXNUM    127 /* 0x7FU, cf. FDNUMMASK */
```

Comment: I believe that the underlying issue is address by the following question: [Syntax error: word unexpected on io redirection on file descriptor ≥10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166805)≥10