# Safe to write to /proc/self/fd/N

Tags: linux, proc

Is it safe to write to /proc/self/fd/N where N is any file descriptor owned by the process.

My use case is to ssh into a remote machine and *cat* many remote files to local files. The local files were created earlier and immediately unlinked so that other user/process cannot see them.

```
fd = open("/tmp/doo",O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
unlink("/tmp/doo");
...
...
system("ssh -n user@remotehost -- cat /remote_file >/proc/self/fd/N") // N is a valid fd number
```

I cannot redirect output to fd (cat /remote_file >&N) because shell allow only 0-9 to be used.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07

> Open files are represented by decimal numbers starting with zero. The
> largest possible value is implementation-defined; however, all
> implementations shall support at least 0 to 9, inclusive, for use by
> the application. These numbers are called "file descriptors". The
> values 0, 1, and 2 have special meaning and conventional uses and are
> implied by certain redirection operations; they are referred to as
> standard input, standard output, and standard error, respectively.
> Programs usually take their input from standard input, and write
> output on standard output. Error messages are usually written on
> standard error. The redirection operators can be preceded by one or
> more digits (with no intervening  characters allowed) to
> designate the file descriptor number.

[Issue with redirecting output to double digit file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717969/issue-with-redirecting-output-to-double-digit-file-descriptor)